# How do I show another window in an IPhone window application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

First of all, I'm new to Objective-C and IPhone programming.  There is somehing I can not get to work. I have a IPhone window application and in the MainWindow I have a button. I want to show another window when I click the button.  I've bind the event with my controller.  I just don't know how to show my other window (otherWindow) in the event.

Anyone can guide to do this ?  Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of adding a `UIView` to your Window when a button is clicked:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
    UIView *newView = [[NewView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 60, 500, 600)];
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
    [newView release];
}
```

This is an example of pushing a new view (assuming you're using a navigationController:

```
LoginViewController *viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

And this is an example of presenting a new view (modal window):

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
```

Comment: Should the comment above your flipping example say "Or **push** a new view"?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that by *"window"* you actually mean a new screenful of contents.

First question is: should the user be able to return to the first screen with the button? If yes then you should use a `UINavigationController`, or a modal view controller.

The `UINavigationController` gives you a navigation bar with a title and "back"-button for free at the top of the screen. Create a new project using the Navigation Template to learn how it works. Using it would be as simple as:

```
-(IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    CWTheNewController* controller = [[[CWTheNewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The navigation controller is just as simple to use, but the new view controller will cover the whole screen, and it is up to you to provide code/UI to dismiss the controller again:

```
-(IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    CWTheNewController* controller = [[[CWTheNewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

If the user should **not** be able to navigate back, then instead do something like this to replace the current contents of the screen completely:

```
-(IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    CWTheNewController* controller = [[[CWTheNewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.view.window.rootViewController = controller;
}
```

Either way the first document you should read up and understand is [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/). **EVERYTHING** you do with iOS should be using view controllers, otherwise you are doing it wrong, and extra hard for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

After creating your window, call `makeKeyWindow` or `makeKeyAndVisible` on it.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone apps typically have only 1 window, as the [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503) says.

If you want to show another 'window', you can add another subview to the 1 and only window.